# Rad Grid Edit Form Control Validations

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I'm new to teleriks.Anyway i want to validate textboxes in edit form.I want to use some regular expression also.How can i do this?
Is there any place to add egular expressions?.Please help me to solve this isssues.

Comment: Please mention Winforms, WPF, ASP.Net. For your question, please refer telerik document there are plenty of examples. If it's for radgrid, you can use MaskedTextBox with Regular expression. See this :http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/editors-maskededitbox-working-with-radmaskededitbox.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are using radgrid you can take several ways here 
check here:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-validation.html